# CodeIgniter - Get a variable within quotes.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to get an variable between quotes in codeigniter. But how do i accomplish this.

> ```
>           $this->db->where('Boekingsdatum >', $start);
> ```

For example the $start has the value 2014-03-17.
then codeigniter sees it like this:

> ```
>           $this->db->where('Boekingsdatum >', 2014-03-17);
> ```

But i would like to have it like this:

> ```
>           $this->db->where('Boekingsdatum >', '2014-03-17');
> ```

So i thought the answer would be something like this:

> ```
>           $this->db->where('Boekingsdatum >', '$start');
> ```
>
> But then the variable is seen as text not as an variable.

Comment: you need `$this->db->where('Boekingsdatum >', "'$start'");` ?

Comment: Then the $start is still seen as text Not as an variable.

Comment: no it's not when a variable is wrap with double quote it will treat it as a variable while wrap in single quotes it will always treat it as a STRING

Answer (score 0):

For dates and only for dates you can do

```
$this->db->where('Boekingsdatum >', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start)));
```